# How to remove selected stackpanel using context menu in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `StackPanel` with children. The `StackPanel` children are also `StackPanel`. Children `StackPanel` is added by dynamically at runtime. I have a context menu with delete header. When I click the delete menu the selected stack children will be deleted. I don't have any idea to remove the `StackPanel` children by using the context menu. Please, anyone, guide me to resolve this. My sample code is as below,

```
<StackPanel x:Name="mainPanel" Background="#F0F0F0">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Click="ParentContextMenu_Click" Header="Add Stackpanel" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Code behind**

```
 public partial class MainView : Window
    {
        ContextMenu contextMenu;
        MenuItem menuItem;
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            menuItem = new MenuItem();
            menuItem.Header = "Delete Panel";
            menuItem.Click += ChildContextMenu_Click;
            contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
        }

        private void ChildContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ParentContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel stack = new StackPanel()
            {
                Name = "childStack"
                Height = 100,
                Width = 100,
                Background = Brushes.White,
                Margin = new Thickness(15, 15, 0, 10),
                ContextMenu = contextMenu
            };

            mainPanel.Children.Add(stack);
        }
    }
```

I have tried like this also, but is not deleted.

```
mainPanel.Children.Remove((StackPanel)this.FindName("childStack"));
```

[image: Please refer the screenshot]

Comment: You've not provided enough information for us to help you. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could do yourself (and us) a favour by using slighllty better names, like  contextMenu -> childContextMenu. Same for the click events. But it is a complete question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void ChildContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
    if (mi != null)
    {
        ContextMenu cm = mi.Parent as ContextMenu;
        if (cm != null)
        {
            StackPanel sp = cm.PlacementTarget as StackPanel;
            if (sp != null)
            {
                Panel parentSp = sp.Parent as Panel;
                if (parentSp != null)
                    parentSp.Children.Remove(sp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```